# How to integrate formstack, wordpress and authorize.net?

Tags: wordpress, forms, api

What are all the steps that involve in integrating formstack with Wordpress CMS?

What are all the steps involved in integrating formstack with authorize.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formstack has this information on their support site:

- [How to use the Formstack WordPress plugin to add forms to a WordPress blog](https://support.formstack.com/customer/portal/articles/1239144-6-5-wordpress-plugin)
- [How to use Authorize.net with Formstack](https://support.formstack.com/customer/portal/articles/1239094-4-1-authorize-net)

There's also a [video walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJiT7x6guUo) of the WordPress plugin here.